# Magento 1.5.0.1 - Where does the Google Sitemap get created?

Tags: magento

I am using Mangento 1.5.0.1 and have configured the admin section to export Google XML Sitemaps daily.

Mangento uses cron to execute this however the cron job runs but never outputs a sitemap nor does it email me an error.

I was thinking maybe I need to manually create the folders / files and then maybe they would then be populated by the cron job.

So my question is, where in the file system does Magento create these files?

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory I think `sitemap.xml` normally gets created in the Magento directory - usually whatever is the public root of your website. Of course this is configurable.

Comment: The path and filename are set when you create or edit a sitemap instruction in _Catalog > Google Sitemap_.

Comment: OMG your right, can't believe I missed it. I was only using config under the Configuration menu. 2 wasted days!! Your a life saver! Cheers Paul

Comment: It's not that surprising, having settings spread out of two areas doesn't make it convenient for everyday use. Perhaps that will be rectified one day.